# Generator of dual lattice.

Tags: matrix-rank, integer-lattices

Let $G\in\Bbb R^{n\times k}$ where $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ be generator of a lattice $\mathcal L\subsetneq\Bbb R^n$ of rank $r\leq k$ (that is $G$ has rank $r$).

That is $\mathcal L=\{y\in\Bbb R^n:\exists x\in\Bbb Z^k\mbox{ with }y=Gx\}$.

What is the generator and rank of dual lattice?

Comment: The generator and rank will be given by the pseudo-inverse of G: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse